Работоспособность приложения после публикации в Google Play
В приложении используется виджет yandex_mapkit для вывода карты. При запуске приложения в эмуляторе или на устройстве из Android Studio карта отображается и выполняет необходимые функции. При загрузке приложения из Google Play карта не отображается и не выполняется метод onMapCreated, как будто виджет карты просто вырезан из приложения. Так как не всплывают никакие ошибки.
pubspec.yaml
yandex_mapkit: ^4.0.2
permission_handler: ^11.3.1

app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<application
     android:name=".MainApplication"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
     <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
[...]

map_screen.dart
YandexMap(
  mapObjects: _mapObjects,
  onMapCreated: (YandexMapController yandexMapController) async {
    _yandexMapController = yandexMapController;
    await _initLocationLayer();
  },
),

Получаю ошибку во время инициализации виджета карты:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: yandex_mapkit/yandex_map
        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.z.M(SourceFile:1)
        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.z$a.d(SourceFile:1)
        at n7.q$a.c(SourceFile:1)
        at n7.q$a.onMethodCall(SourceFile:1)
        at o7.k$a.a(SourceFile:1)
        at f7.c.l(SourceFile:1)
        at f7.c.m(SourceFile:1)
        at f7.c.i(SourceFile:1)
        at f7.b.run(SourceFile:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
    , null, null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      ExpensiveAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1099)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:822)
    <asynchronous suspension>

Проблема устранена автором виджета в новой версии.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

Пожалуйста, пришлите нам полный пример кода. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub, прикрепить к переписке в архиве или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку.

Попробуйте выполнить интеграцию через официальный MapKit for Flutter. По используемому вами виджету стоит задавать вопрос его автору.
